# 404 Error on existing pages

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp-classic

Have an issue where I get a 404 errors on multiple pages that definitely exist on the server.
It is an ASP based website and at completely random points I get a 404 error for those pages that definitely exist on the server as after I do a refresh it's absolutely fine.

Weird thing is that when I open developer tools I never receive the error anymore.
Any chance that developers tools is actually interfering with the connection between browser and server and actually changes something?
Why I'm not getting the error while developer tools is running?

Has anybody got anything similar to this before?
I am using Internet Explorer 11 as well as tried Internet Explorer 10. 
Same on both browsers.

Comment: I take it you're running this on an IIS server correct?  Have you enabled Failed Request Tracing?  Just wondering if it is a true 404 on the server vs. something client/browser based.

Comment: Yes, it runs on IIS.
It's not an actual 404 as files do exist on the server because when I refresh the page it opens it fine...
I will try to enable failed request tracing and see what that gives me.

Comment: I am currently having the same issue, any insight from when you tested would be appreciated